# Raise X to the power of N. Code not working for negative exponents

Tags: c++

I'm working on a code which must calculate a Base to the power of an Exponent. Code seems to be correct if i input whatever Base and a non-negative Exponent.

The code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int n;  //The Exponent
int x;  //The Base
double result;

int main(){
    pleaseInput:
    cout << "Enter Base: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Now enter Exponent: ";
    cin >> n;
    //If the base is 0 could be tricky...
    if(x==0){
        if(n==0){
            //0 ^ 0 = 1
            result = 1;
        }else if(n>0){
            //0 ^ 3 = 0
            result = 0;
        }else if(n<0){
            //0 ^ -2 is undefined.
            cout << "0 to the power of a negative exponent is an undefined math operation. Please enter valid data. " << endl;
            goto pleaseInput;
        }
    //If the base is other than 0...
    }else{
        //If the exponent is not 0...
        if(n!=0){
            //Make the exponent unsigned to know the amoun of iterations regardless its sign.
            unsigned int exp = (unsigned int)n;
            result = 1;
            for(int i=0;i<exp;i++){
                result *= x;    
            }
            //If the exponent was negative...
            if(n<0){
                result = 1/result;          
            }
        //If X^0....
        }else{
            result = 1;
        }
        cout << x <<" to the power of "<< n <<" equals "<< result << endl;
    }
}
```

Please could you guys take a look and help me find where is the mistake?

Thanks a lot in advance!!
Guillermo.

Comment: This line `unsigned int exp = (unsigned int)n;` does not do what you want it to. Use your debugger and examine `exp` after the assignment when `n` is negative.

Comment: FYI there is a standard function std::pow that does the thing, assuming that's not a homework question.

Comment: FYI 2.0: =[0^0 is not 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form) as you may be thinking

Comment: @Richard Critten: Believe or not, i've never use a debugger, so i'm actually working on it.Thanks!!

Comment: That's good, it's the 2nd most vital tool if you want to be a good programmer (the 1st being your brain)

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ That's what my calculator says  0^0=1. AFAIK nay number to the power of 0, including 0 itself, equals 1. Isn't it correct?

Comment: Have a read of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow  especially the error handling section.

Comment: My comprehension on C++ language is very poor, so I still don't understand why that statement wasn't working, but when you gave me the tip i went for another solution. Found 'abs()' and it did the job. I'll edit the code. I appreciate your help very much! Thanks a lot, guys!!

Comment: @RichardCritten i'm taking a look right now. Looks a little complex for the point i am, but it's good to have that C++ reference in hand from now on. Thanks again.

Comment: Please don't change your question to an answer, since an answer without a question does not make a lot of sense for future readers. If you would like to present your solution, please do so in an answer.

Comment: 0^0 is considered by mathematicians to be one, but it's like 0/0, an undefined form and you can't expect a computer to handle it without special programming.

Comment: @halfer Sorry Sir, will do better in the future.

Comment: No need to apologise @Calfa, but would you add an answer on this question? Click on the 'Add Your Answer' button below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, excuse me if i'm not doing it properly, but it's my first time.

In the code on the OP, there was a statement:

```
unsigned int exp = (unsigned int)n;
```

I used it in order to remove the possible '-' sign from the exponent to iterate through the loop as many times as needed.

@RichardCritten told me that this line wasn't doing what I expected, and I finally realized that the way to do this was:

```
unsigned int exp = abs(n);
```

Thanks everyone for your help!